# adding a java application to system configuration start up menu

Tags: java

I am creating a desktop application. I know how to add program to system tray,  that consists of a continuous system process, I need instructions on how to add java code to system configuration startup menu. Like antivirus program which automatically executes on starting the system. would be of great help with example code

Comment: Downvotes are because you haven't tried to do it yourself yet. SO isn't a code factory.

Comment: At minimum, we'd need to know which operating system(s) you're targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Write a batch file(.bat) which executes you java program. Add this batch file into the registry in such a way that it will be executed during system startup.

simply write following into your batch file

```
java filename
```

In linux you will hv to create a .sh script(executable) that will execute your java program.

put .sh in /etc/rc0.d using following commands

```
cp name.sh /etc/rc0.d/
chmod +x /etc/rc0.d/name.sh
```